# Cannot read property 'call' of jquery.validate.min.js:16 undefined

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, anchor

Good day,

In my jsp, I have a link button to let user click, and it will direct user to another page.

My jsp code as follow:

```
<a class="view" style="padding-left:50px;" href="javascript:addRefNo('addKpRefNo');">
                    addKpRefNo
                </a>
```

And below is my script method:

```
function addRefNo(event){
    if(event != ""){
    var form = $("form[name=corporateForm]");
        form.attr("action", '<s:url beanclass="com.app.maint.ui.CorporateAction" event="addKpRefNo"/>');
    form.submit();
    }else {
    }
}
```

And then is my java code:

```
public Resolution addKpRefNo() {
        // do some logic here

        return new ForwardResolution( ADD_KP_REF_NO_PAGE ).addParameter(
                "editMode", isEditMode( ) );
    }
```

However, I am hitting some javaScript issue when I click on the link button. Previously its working. Here is the error of Chrome console:
[image]

I am using jQuery v1.3.2 and jQuery validation plug-in 1.5.1.

Jquery validation plugin:

```
/*
 * jQuery validation plug-in 1.5.1
 *
 * http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
 * http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 - 2008 Jörn Zaefferer
 *
 * $Id: jquery.validate.js 6096 2009-01-12 14:12:04Z joern.zaefferer $
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */
(function($){$.extend($.fn,{validate:function(options){if(!this.length){options&&options.debug&&window.console&&console.warn("nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing");return;}var validator=$.data(this[0],'validator');if(validator){return validator;}validator=new $.validator(options,this[0]);$.data(this[0],'validator',validator);if(validator.settings.onsubmit){this.find("input, button").filter(".cancel").click(function(){validator.cancelSubmit=true;});this.submit(function(event){if(validator.settings.debug)event.preventDefault();function handle(){if(validator.settings.submitHandler){validator.settings.submitHandler.call(validator,validator.currentForm);return false;}return true;}if(validator.cancelSubmit){validator.cancelSubmit=false;return handle();}if(validator.form()){if(validator.pendingRequest){validator.formSubmitted=true;return false;}return handle();}else{validator.focusInvalid();return false;}});}return validator;},valid:function(){if($(this[0]).is('form')){return this.validate().form();}else{var valid=false;var validator=$(this[0].form).validate();this.each(function(){valid|=validator.element(this);});return valid;}},removeAttrs:function(attributes){var result={},$element=this;$.each(attributes.split(/\s/),function(index,value){result[value]=$element.attr(value);$element.removeAttr(value);});return result;},rules:function(command,argument){var element=this[0];if(command){var settings=$.data(element.form,'validator').settings;var staticRules=settings.rules;var existingRules=$.validator.staticRules(element);switch(command){case"add":$.extend(existingRules,$.validator.normalizeRule(argument));staticRules[element.name]=existingRules;if(argument.messages)settings.messages[element.name]=$.extend(settings.messages[element.name],argument.messages);break;case"remove":if(!argument){delete staticRules[element.name];return existingRules;}var filtered={};$.each(argument.split(/\s/),function(index,method){filtered[method]=existingRules[method];delete existingRules[method];});return filtered;}}var data=$.validator.normalizeRules($.extend({},$.validator.metadataRules(element),$.validator.classRules(element),$.validator.attributeRules(element),$.validator.staticRules(element)),element);if(data.required){var param=data.required;delete data.required;data=$.extend({required:param},data);}return data;}});$.extend($.expr[":"],{blank:function(a){return!$.trim(a.value);},filled:function(a){return!!$.trim(a.value);},unchecked:function(a){return!a.checked;}});$.format=function(source,params){if(arguments.length==1)return function(){var args=$.makeArray(arguments);args.unshift(source);return $.format.apply(this,args);};if(arguments.length>2&&params.constructor!=Array){params=$.makeArray(arguments).slice(1);}if(params.constructor!=Array){params=[params];}$.each(params,function(i,n){source=source.replace(new RegExp("\\{"+i+"\\}","g"),n);});return source;};$.validator=function(options,form){this.settings=$.extend({},$.validator.defaults,options);this.currentForm=form;this.init();};$.extend($.validator,{defaults:{messages:{},groups:{},rules:{},errorClass:"error",errorElement:"label",focusInvalid:true,errorContainer:$([]),errorLabelContainer:$([]),onsubmit:true,ignore:[],ignoreTitle:false,onfocusin:function(element){this.lastActive=element;if(this.settings.focusCleanup&&!this.blockFocusCleanup){this.settings.unhighlight&&this.settings.unhighlight.call(this,element,this.settings.errorClass);this.errorsFor(element).hide();}},onfocusout:function(element){if(!this.checkable(element)&&(element.name in this.submitted||!this.optional(element))){this.element(element);}},onkeyup:function(element){if(element.name in this.submitted||element==this.lastElement){this.element(element);}},onclick:function(element){if(element.name in this.submitted)this.element(element);},highlight:function(element,errorClass){$(element).addClass(errorClass);},unhighlight:function(element,errorClass){$(element).removeClass(errorClass);}},setDefaults:function(settings){$.extend($.validator.defaults,settings);},messages:{required:"This field is a mandatory field.",remote:"Please fix this field.",email:"Please enter a valid email address.",url:"Please enter a valid URL.",date:"Please enter a valid date.",dateISO:"Please enter a valid date (ISO).",dateDE:"Bitte geben Sie ein gültiges Datum ein.",number:"Please enter a valid number.",numberDE:"Bitte geben Sie eine Nummer ein.",digits:"Please enter only digits",creditcard:"Please enter a valid credit card number.",equalTo:"Please enter the same value again.",accept:"Please enter a value with a valid extension.",maxlength:$.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),minlength:$.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),rangelength:$.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),range:$.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),max:$.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),min:$.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")},autoCreateRanges:false,prototype:{init:function(){this.labelContainer=$(this.settings.errorLabelContainer);this.errorContext=this.labelContainer.length&&this.labelContainer||$(this.currentForm);this.containers=$(this.settings.errorContainer).add(this.settings.errorLabelContainer);this.submitted={};this.valueCache={};this.pendingRequest=0;this.pending={};this.invalid={};this.reset();var groups=(this.groups={});$.each(this.settings.groups,function(key,value){$.each(value.split(/\s/),function(index,name){groups[name]=key;});});var rules=this.settings.rules;$.each(rules,function(key,value){rules[key]=$.validator.normalizeRule(value);});function delegate(event){var validator=$.data(this[0].form,"validator");validator.settings["on"+event.type]&&validator.settings["on"+event.type].call(validator,this[0]);}$(this.currentForm).delegate("focusin focusout keyup",":text, :password, :file, select, textarea",delegate).delegate("click",":radio, :checkbox",delegate);if(this.settings.invalidHandler)$(this.currentForm).bind("invalid-form.validate",this.settings.invalidHandler);},form:function(){this.checkForm();$.extend(this.submitted,this.errorMap);this.invalid=$.extend({},this.errorMap);if(!this.valid())$(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form",[this]);this.showErrors();return this.valid();},checkForm:function(){this.prepareForm();for(var i=0,elements=(this.currentElements=this.elements());elements[i];i++){this.check(elements[i]);}return this.valid();},element:function(element){element=this.clean(element);this.lastElement=element;this.prepareElement(element);this.currentElements=$(element);var result=this.check(element);if(result){delete this.invalid[element.name];}else{this.invalid[element.name]=true;}if(!this.numberOfInvalids()){this.toHide=this.toHide.add(this.containers);}this.showErrors();return result;},showErrors:function(errors){if(errors){$.extend(this.errorMap,errors);this.errorList=[];for(var name in errors){this.errorList.push({message:errors[name],element:this.findByName(name)[0]});}this.successList=$.grep(this.successList,function(element){return!(element.name in errors);});}this.settings.showErrors?this.settings.showErrors.call(this,this.errorMap,this.errorList):this.defaultShowErrors();},resetForm:function(){if($.fn.resetForm)$(this.currentForm).resetForm();this.submitted={};this.prepareForm();this.hideErrors();this.elements().removeClass(this.settings.errorClass);},numberOfInvalids:function(){return this.objectLength(this.invalid);},objectLength:function(obj){var count=0;for(var i in obj)count++;return count;},hideErrors:function(){this.addWrapper(this.toHide).hide();},valid:function(){return this.size()==0;},size:function(){return this.errorList.length;},focusInvalid:function(){if(this.settings.focusInvalid){try{$(this.findLastActive()||this.errorList.length&&this.errorList[0].element||[]).filter(":visible").focus();}catch(e){}}},findLastActive:function(){var lastActive=this.lastActive;return lastActive&&$.grep(this.errorList,function(n){return n.element.name==lastActive.name;}).length==1&&lastActive;},elements:function(){var validator=this,rulesCache={};return $([]).add(this.currentForm.elements).filter(":input").not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]").not(this.settings.ignore).filter(function(){!this.name&&validator.settings.debug&&window.console&&console.error("%o has no name assigned",this);if(this.name in rulesCache||!validator.objectLength($(this).rules()))return false;rulesCache[this.name]=true;return true;});},clean:function(selector){return $(selector)[0];},errors:function(){return $(this.settings.errorElement+"."+this.settings.errorClass,this.errorContext);},reset:function(){this.successList=[];this.errorList=[];this.errorMap={};this.toShow=$([]);this.toHide=$([]);this.formSubmitted=false;this.currentElements=$([]);},prepareForm:function(){this.reset();this.toHide=this.errors().add(this.containers);},prepareElement:function(element){this.reset();this.toHide=this.errorsFor(element);},check:function(element){element=this.clean(element);if(this.checkable(element)){element=this.findByName(element.name)[0];}var rules=$(element).rules();var dependencyMismatch=false;for(method in rules){var rule={method:method,parameters:rules[method]};try{var result=$.validator.methods[method].call(this,element.value,element,rule.parameters);if(result=="dependency-mismatch"){dependencyMismatch=true;continue;}dependencyMismatch=false;if(result=="pending"){this.toHide=this.toHide.not(this.errorsFor(element));return;}if(!result){this.formatAndAdd(element,rule);return false;}}catch(e){this.settings.debug&&window.console&&console.log("exception occured when checking element "+element.id
+", check the '"+rule.method+"' method");throw e;}}if(dependencyMismatch)return;if(this.objectLength(rules))this.successList.push(element);return true;},customMetaMessage:function(element,method){if(!$.metadata)return;var meta=this.settings.meta?$(element).metadata()[this.settings.meta]:$(element).metadata();return meta&&meta.messages&&meta.messages[method];},customMessage:function(name,method){var m=this.settings.messages[name];return m&&(m.constructor==String?m:m[method]);},findDefined:function(){for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){if(arguments[i]!==undefined)return arguments[i];}return undefined;},defaultMessage:function(element,method){return this.findDefined(this.customMessage(element.name,method),this.customMetaMessage(element,method),!this.settings.ignoreTitle&&element.title||undefined,$.validator.messages[method],"<strong>Warning: No message defined for "+element.name+"</strong>");},formatAndAdd:function(element,rule){var message=this.defaultMessage(element,rule.method);if(typeof message=="function")message=message.call(this,rule.parameters,element);this.errorList.push({message:message,element:element});this.errorMap[element.name]=message;this.submitted[element.name]=message;},addWrapper:function(toToggle){if(this.settings.wrapper)toToggle=toToggle.add(toToggle.parents(this.settings.wrapper));return toToggle;},defaultShowErrors:function(){for(var i=0;this.errorList[i];i++){var error=this.errorList[i];this.settings.highlight&&this.settings.highlight.call(this,error.element,this.settings.errorClass);this.showLabel(error.element,error.message);}if(this.errorList.length){this.toShow=this.toShow.add(this.containers);}if(this.settings.success){for(var i=0;this.successList[i];i++){this.showLabel(this.successList[i]);}}if(this.settings.unhighlight){for(var i=0,elements=this.validElements();elements[i];i++){this.settings.unhighlight.call(this,elements[i],this.settings.errorClass);}}this.toHide=this.toHide.not(this.toShow);this.hideErrors();this.addWrapper(this.toShow).show();},validElements:function(){return this.currentElements.not(this.invalidElements());},invalidElements:function(){return $(this.errorList).map(function(){return this.element;});},showLabel:function(element,message){var label=this.errorsFor(element);if(label.length){label.removeClass().addClass(this.settings.errorClass);label.attr("generated")&&label.html(message);}else{label=$("<"+this.settings.errorElement+"/>").attr({"for":this.idOrName(element),generated:true}).addClass(this.settings.errorClass).html(message||"");if(this.settings.wrapper){label=label.hide().show().wrap("<"+this.settings.wrapper+"/>").parent();}if(!this.labelContainer.append(label).length)this.settings.errorPlacement?this.settings.errorPlacement(label,$(element)):label.insertAfter(element);}if(!message&&this.settings.success){label.text("");typeof this.settings.success=="string"?label.addClass(this.settings.success):this.settings.success(label);}this.toShow=this.toShow.add(label);},errorsFor:function(element){return this.errors().filter("[for='"+this.idOrName(element)+"']");},idOrName:function(element){return this.groups[element.name]||(this.checkable(element)?element.name:element.id||element.name);},checkable:function(element){return/radio|checkbox/i.test(element.type);},findByName:function(name){var form=this.currentForm;return $(document.getElementsByName(name)).map(function(index,element){return element.form==form&&element.name==name&&element||null;});},getLength:function(value,element){switch(element.nodeName.toLowerCase()){case'select':return $("option:selected",element).length;case'input':if(this.checkable(element))return this.findByName(element.name).filter(':checked').length;}return value.length;},depend:function(param,element){return this.dependTypes[typeof param]?this.dependTypes[typeof param](param,element):true;},dependTypes:{"boolean":function(param,element){return param;},"string":function(param,element){return!!$(param,element.form).length;},"function":function(param,element){return param(element);}},optional:function(element){return!$.validator.methods.required.call(this,$.trim(element.value),element)&&"dependency-mismatch";},startRequest:function(element){if(!this.pending[element.name]){this.pendingRequest++;this.pending[element.name]=true;}},stopRequest:function(element,valid){this.pendingRequest--;if(this.pendingRequest<0)this.pendingRequest=0;delete this.pending[element.name];if(valid&&this.pendingRequest==0&&this.formSubmitted&&this.form()){$(this.currentForm).submit();}else if(!valid&&this.pendingRequest==0&&this.formSubmitted){$(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form",[this]);}},previousValue:function(element){return $.data(element,"previousValue")||$.data(element,"previousValue",previous={old:null,valid:true,message:this.defaultMessage(element,"remote")});}},classRuleSettings:{required:{required:true},email:{email:true},url:{url:true},date:{date:true},dateISO:{dateISO:true},dateDE:{dateDE:true},number:{number:true},numberDE:{numberDE:true},digits:{digits:true},creditcard:{creditcard:true}},addClassRules:function(className,rules){className.constructor==String?this.classRuleSettings[className]=rules:$.extend(this.classRuleSettings,className);},classRules:function(element){var rules={};var classes=$(element).attr('class');classes&&$.each(classes.split(' '),function(){if(this in $.validator.classRuleSettings){$.extend(rules,$.validator.classRuleSettings[this]);}});return rules;},attributeRules:function(element){var rules={};var $element=$(element);for(method in $.validator.methods){var value=$element.attr(method);if(value){rules[method]=value;}}if(rules.maxlength&&/-1|2147483647|524288/.test(rules.maxlength)){delete rules.maxlength;}return rules;},metadataRules:function(element){if(!$.metadata)return{};var meta=$.data(element.form,'validator').settings.meta;return meta?$(element).metadata()[meta]:$(element).metadata();},staticRules:function(element){var rules={};var validator=$.data(element.form,'validator');if(validator.settings.rules){rules=$.validator.normalizeRule(validator.settings.rules[element.name])||{};}return rules;},normalizeRules:function(rules,element){$.each(rules,function(prop,val){if(val===false){delete rules[prop];return;}if(val.param||val.depends){var keepRule=true;switch(typeof val.depends){case"string":keepRule=!!$(val.depends,element.form).length;break;case"function":keepRule=val.depends.call(element,element);break;}if(keepRule){rules[prop]=val.param!==undefined?val.param:true;}else{delete rules[prop];}}});$.each(rules,function(rule,parameter){rules[rule]=$.isFunction(parameter)?parameter(element):parameter;});$.each(['minlength','maxlength','min','max'],function(){if(rules[this]){rules[this]=Number(rules[this]);}});$.each(['rangelength','range'],function(){if(rules[this]){rules[this]=[Number(rules[this][0]),Number(rules[this][1])];}});if($.validator.autoCreateRanges){if(rules.min&&rules.max){rules.range=[rules.min,rules.max];delete rules.min;delete rules.max;}if(rules.minlength&&rules.maxlength){rules.rangelength=[rules.minlength,rules.maxlength];delete rules.minlength;delete rules.maxlength;}}if(rules.messages){delete rules.messages}return rules;},normalizeRule:function(data){if(typeof data=="string"){var transformed={};$.each(data.split(/\s/),function(){transformed[this]=true;});data=transformed;}return data;},addMethod:function(name,method,message){$.validator.methods[name]=method;$.validator.messages[name]=message;if(method.length<3){$.validator.addClassRules(name,$.validator.normalizeRule(name));}},methods:{required:function(value,element,param){if(!this.depend(param,element))return"dependency-mismatch";switch(element.nodeName.toLowerCase()){case'select':var options=$("option:selected",element);return options.length>0&&(element.type=="select-multiple"||($.browser.msie&&!(options[0].attributes['value'].specified)?options[0].text:options[0].value).length>0);case'input':if(this.checkable(element))return this.getLength(value,element)>0;default:return $.trim(value).length>0;}},remote:function(value,element,param){if(this.optional(element))return"dependency-mismatch";var previous=this.previousValue(element);if(!this.settings.messages[element.name])this.settings.messages[element.name]={};this.settings.messages[element.name].remote=typeof previous.message=="function"?previous.message(value):previous.message;param=typeof param=="string"&&{url:param}||param;if(previous.old!==value){previous.old=value;var validator=this;this.startRequest(element);var data={};data[element.name]=value;$.ajax($.extend(true,{url:param,mode:"abort",port:"validate"+element.name,dataType:"json",data:data,success:function(response){if(response){var submitted=validator.formSubmitted;validator.prepareElement(element);validator.formSubmitted=submitted;validator.successList.push(element);validator.showErrors();}else{var errors={};errors[element.name]=response||validator.defaultMessage(element,"remote");validator.showErrors(errors);}previous.valid=response;validator.stopRequest(element,response);}},param));return"pending";}else if(this.pending[element.name]){return"pending";}return previous.valid;},minlength:function(value,element,param){return this.optional(element)||this.getLength($.trim(value),element)>=param;},maxlength:function(value,element,param){return this.optional(element)||this.getLength($.trim(value),element)<=param;},rangelength:function(value,element,param){var length=this.getLength($.trim(value),element);return this.optional(element)||(length>=param[0]&&length<=param[1]);},min:function(value,element,param){return this.optional(element)||value>=param;},max:function(value,element,param){return this.optional(element)||value<=param;},range:function(value,element,param){return this.optional(element)||(value>=param[0]&&value<=param[1]);},email:function(value,element){return this.optional(element)||/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i.test(value);},url:function(value,element){return this.optional(element)||/^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(value);},date:function(value,element){var dateParts = value.split("/");return this.optional(element)||!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1) ,dateParts[0]));},dateISO:function(value,element){return this.optional(element)||/^\d{4}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}$/.test(value);},dateDE:function(value,element){return this.optional(element)||/^\d\d?\.\d\d?\.\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);},number:function(value,element){return this.optional(element)||/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);},numberDE:function(value,element){return this.optional(element)||/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);},digits:function(value,element){return this.optional(element)||/^\d+$/.test(value);},creditcard:function(value,element){if(this.optional(element))return"dependency-mismatch";if(/[^0-9-]+/.test(value))return false;var nCheck=0,nDigit=0,bEven=false;value=value.replace(/\D/g,"");for(n=value.length-1;n>=0;n--){var cDigit=value.charAt(n);var nDigit=parseInt(cDigit,10);if(bEven){if((nDigit*=2)>9)nDigit-=9;}nCheck+=nDigit;bEven=!bEven;}return(nCheck%10)==0;},accept:function(value,element,param){param=typeof param=="string"?param:"png|jpe?g|gif";return this.optional(element)||value.match(new RegExp(".("+param+")$","i"));},equalTo:function(value,element,param){return value==$(param).val();}}});})(jQuery);;(function($){var ajax=$.ajax;var pendingRequests={};$.ajax=function(settings){settings=$.extend(settings,$.extend({},$.ajaxSettings,settings));var port=settings.port;if(settings.mode=="abort"){if(pendingRequests[port]){pendingRequests[port].abort();}return(pendingRequests[port]=ajax.apply(this,arguments));}return ajax.apply(this,arguments);};})(jQuery);;(function($){$.each({focus:'focusin',blur:'focusout'},function(original,fix){$.event.special[fix]={setup:function(){if($.browser.msie)return false;this.addEventListener(original,$.event.special[fix].handler,true);},teardown:function(){if($.browser.msie)return false;this.removeEventListener(original,$.event.special[fix].handler,true);},handler:function(e){arguments[0]=$.event.fix(e);arguments[0].type=fix;return $.event.handle.apply(this,arguments);}};});$.extend($.fn,{delegate:function(type,delegate,handler){return this.bind(type,function(event){var target=$(event.target);if(target.is(delegate)){return handler.apply(target,arguments);}});},triggerEvent:function(type,target){return this.triggerHandler(type,[$.event.fix({type:type,target:target})]);}})})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I believe not the same case. My case is regarding the javaScript error, uncaught type error. The another post is regarding Ajax asynchronous issue.